# GAS in Sheets submit function does not work as another user

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a very simple version that still shows the issue and can be viewed and tested by anyone.

My problem is the onclick events do not ever get called unless you are the owner even when the sheet is shared with the world.

Please follow the link below, to try out the issue

[My Simple Example to Try](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j5Z38Q0AKmCHjjVqzjY7sjulG5um2dejJSxJhj-woPY)

Here is the simple code:

```js
//Global reused variables
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var pageTxt;
var html;

function onLoad(){
  pageTxt = ''; 
  pageTxt += '<h2><b>Click on this button, it should pop up and say Hello World but it does not work when it is not run as the owner, why?</b></h2><br><br>';
  pageTxt += '<TR><TD><input onclick="formSubmit()" type="button" value="Submit" style="height:30px; width:100px" /></TD><TD> </TD>';
  pageTxt += '<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById("UniqueCode").focus(); function formSubmit() { google.script.run.EventHandler(document.forms[0]); } </script>';
  html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(pageTxt);
  html.setTitle("Simple Example of my issue");
  ss.show(html);
}


//RecieveUniqueCode
function EventHandler(form){
  Browser.msgBox("Hello World");
  onLoad();
}
```

I am hoping someone to work out why when clicking the submit button as another user it does nothing.

If I add another button to close the form this works:

```html
<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
```

It just can't run a custom function in the app script.

**Update:**

I tried manually running the function as the other user and it poped up and asked for authorization

[image]

I think I am close to understanding the issue, although as the owner I have given the user permission to my sheet, because the script interacts with sheets it seems like the user also has to give my script permission to play with the sheet, a bit strange really. So I guess I need to find a way to force it to ask the permission instead of doing nothing when it needs it.

I can also now confirm that accepting the authorization means the simple script now works. It does not give the option when autorun i.e. onload but does when you run a function manually from script editor. how can I do this at run-time?
Any ideas??

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Checked the HTML output and it looks ok "<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById("UniqueCode").focus(); function formSubmit() { google.script.run.RecieveUniqueCode(document.forms[0]); } </script>" So it must be that this method of calling a script does not work for other uses when you share it. Does anyone know why or the correct way to execute a script from a button in html?

Comment: Not sure how much difference this will make in this particular situation, but what type of permissions are set for this other user? Just view, or edit as well?

Comment: Anyone with this link can edit and the user has logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google referance](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#common_errors)

**Authorization is required to perform that action.**

This error indicates that the script is lacking the authorization needed to run. When a script is run in the Script Editor or from a custom menu item an authorization dialog is presented to the user. However, when a script is run as a service, embedded with a Google Sites page, or run from a trigger the dialog cannot be presented and this error is shown. To authorize the script, open the Script Editor and run any function. To avoid this error, remember to run the script once in the Script Editor after adding new services or capabilities to your script.

So unless you are happy that every user you send this too has to run it manually the first time from the script editor then this flaw will stop you from ever deploying an automated sheet to anyone. Very disappointed in google apps :(

Comment: There's got to be another way. I know there is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are heading in the right direction. If I open of my console in chrome and see what happens when the button is clicked an error pops up. See the screenshot.

[image: Dev console error]

Not sure yet why or how to resolve it. I'll keep investigating though.

**Update:** Opened up the script editor, and attempted to run one of the functions manually, the script then prompted for authorization. Once authorized, I went back to the sheet and the formSubmit() function worked as expected (no errors in console).

Comment: Thanks there must be a way to force it to ask for authorization, BTW how did you get to view that error as it would have saved me some time.

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome also, sorry new to this.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+i ... Then navigate to the console tab. It must be up and running to catch any errors when page is loaded though.

Comment: So I will google and see if I can work out how to force it ask them for authorization.

Comment: One idea might be to play around with publishing the script as an addon. Not sure what'll change, or what all the steps are really, but worth a shot.

Comment: Honestly, I don't even see how that onLoad event is being called in your Code.gs file. I believe the only open/load event is, onOpen(e). Therefore, how are you getting that function called? Might just be a blonde moment for me.

Comment: I have connected the trigger to the sheet onload event to point to onLoad

Comment: Just found the following in google developers Page: Authorization is required to perform that action.
This error indicates that the script is lacking the authorization needed to run. When a script is run in the Script Editor or from a custom menu item an authorization dialog is presented to the user. However, when a script is run as a service, embedded with a Google Sites page, or run from a trigger the dialog cannot be presented and this error is shown.

Comment: To authorize the script, open the Script Editor and run any function. To avoid this error, remember to run the script once in the Script Editor after adding new services or capabilities to your script.

Comment: Actually, now that you have pointed out that trigger, I think that may be where your issue is. Try this. Delete that trigger. Change all refferences to onLoad to onOpen. Run the function first from the script editor to ensure any authorization is run. Then refresh your sheet and see that that it's called properly. Then try another user. Then we'll see what happens...

Comment: So what I am trying to do does not sound possible, I can't believe it as almost any script I would write for others to use I wouldn't want them to have to run from the script editor

Comment: In fact I doubt any of my users would even know what the script editor is